# wine without capturing mouse

Tags: virtual-machine, virtual, wine

I wonder, can I use wine like a sort of virtual machine? I mean, can I run windows programs without mouse / keyboard capturing? 
Second question, connected with the first one, how does several programs, run with wine, interact with each other? For example, do they see each other processes and can they read each other memory?

If I can't do it with wine, is there wine analogs, that can do it?

P.S.
I do not consider virtual machines because it is very heavy program, and wine uses much lesser resources

Comment: if the program are in the same wine prefix , they can see eatch other , but if they are run under different prefixes ,they will not see eatch other

Answer (score 0):

Wine does not 'capture' the keyboard and mouse like virtual machine software usually does - whatever program you run in wine is able to interact with your keyboard and mouse in the same manner any other application running on your machine does, since the window is actually handled by your operating system like any other desktop software. Certain games may capture the mouse, the same way they do on windows.

In much the same way, wine doesn't really sandbox your application  like a virtual machine does - the application, if it chose to, could do anything that any other software run as your user account could do.

That said, running incompatible software simultaneously in two different *wine prefixes* can usually be done.